# Update single kernel module / driver

Tags: linux, ubuntu, drivers, kernel

I needed a newer version of a Kernel module in an quite old kernel.

How can I replace a single kernel module of the mainstream linux kernel and compile only this module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One warning: There is no gurantee, that the new driver version is compatible with the old kernel. But it is worth a try.

1. Find the newer driver in the kernel. There are two options: You can use the original kernel driver from the kernel git, for example in https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/drivers. It is handy to select a tag to find the specific kernel version you need. Download the specific `thedriver.h` and `thedriver.c` files and put them into a new directory.

   The second option is to fetch Ubuntu's new kernel from http://packages.ubuntu.com or via `apt-get source ...`
2. Install the packages `build-essentials` and the `linux-kernel-headers`
3. Now we create a makefile for this single module as shown on [cyberciti.biz](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/build-linux-kernel-module-against-installed-kernel-source-tree.html), `thedriver.o` has to be replaced by the driver name.
   In the folder which contains the driver code, create a file `Makefile` with the following content:

   ```
   obj-m += thedriver.o

   all:
       make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

   clean:
       make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
   ```
4. Now, in this directory, type `make` to compile the driver.
5. If everything works well, a `thedriver.ko` file should have been created that can be placed into the folder `/lib/modules/$kernelversion/kernel/drivers` (do not forget to create a backup)